# MMO game made with Unity

Tags: c#

this is my first post in stack exchange i am currently making a 2D MMO game with Unity 5 and Bolt engine for the networking

but i realized that a friend of mine has already made a Fan based game with is own server codded by himself what is the good part of making a custom server and will a bolt engine can provide me with that much performance ?

i need you help could you contact me on skype if your free ?

: sreenandhu4

Comment: Hello and welcome to Gamedev.SE! I'm not sure what you are asking here and if it is what i think, it's still too broad to answer and you will have better luck on some game development forum, like GameDev.net.

Comment: Some clarifications would help. What exactly is the problem? Are you trying to decide on whether to use [Bolt](http://www.boltengine.com/)? What makes you think a custom server will be faster?

Answer (score 2):

Don't get discouraged on your first, but this is a very low-quality question for this site. The "best" answers for this will be to pick one, implement it, then profile it if/when you encounter performance problems. You may be trying to solve a problem, today, that you'll never even have.

**In general:**
Using a library from someone else has the generic advantage of you not having to know how all of the guts work and/or write and debug all of the code yourself. Bolt has many users and when the author screws up a revision, there are many people to let them know exactly how. If you design your own and it doesn't work, you are out of luck.

The primary disadvantage of using third-party libraries is that after you integrate them, you must do everything "their way". You may find, later, that Bolt doesn't do everything you need and/or does some things in ways that you don't like.